# How is the Max-Q of a spacecraft determined?

Tags: testing, measurement, max-q, qualification-testing

Maximum aerodynamic pressure of a spacecraft is the maximum force it's hull can withstand during flight. How is the Max-Q of a spacecraft determined?

Other related ( optional) queries are:

- If Max-Q is also measurable on the ground, how are the simulated external forces applied to the DUT( Device Under Test)?
- Which part of the craft is most vulnerable to such aerodynamic stress?

Comment: Please, ask one question per question. If you have multiple questions, ask multiple questions. Your first question seems to have a rather simple answer, though: aerodynamic pressure is force pushing against the vehicle. You test it by pushing against the vehicle.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Thanks. Thought the short piecemeal questions will spam here.

Comment: @seccpur I've edited the question to make it clearer that you are asking about the maximum aerodynamic pressure a spacecraft can withstand, and not asking about MaxQ (the maximum (peak) dynamic pressure a rocket actually experiences during launch. I think the three questions are so closely related that supporting sources that answer one have a good chance of answering the other two as well.

Comment: @JörgWMittag a careful reading of the original question shows that the OP was not really asking about MaxQ, but instead asking about testing for the maximum dynamic pressure that a rocket can actually experience before failure. Within this context I think the three aspects of the question are suitable for answering all together and probably don't need to be separated out into three different questions.

Comment: A lot of modeling and simulation is done beforehand to predict stress/vibration loads from the chosen design.

Comment: @JörgWMittag How is the force applied to the vehicle structure?

Comment: Hey, that's an excellent question. Now I want to know too. How exactly do we test for the max dynamic pressure a rocket can bear?

Comment: If the question is asking "Does the actual vehicle structure get tested to max q on the ground" the answer is no.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I think that's a fair interpretation of the question, *but let's find out!*

Comment: @seccpur *Is that a fair interpretation of the question?* (see above)

Comment: @uhoh: That's definitely fair interpretation of the question. Can the data be deduced from wind tunnel experiments at high velocity?

Comment: @seccpur there are several ways to phrase your question: 1) "How is X tested on the ground?" 2) "Has X *ever been tested* on the ground, if so, how?" 3) "How to engineers know or at least estimate X? Are wind tunnels ever used to validate these models in some way?"  I recommend rewriting your question to look more like #3 in order to generate some interesting and informative answers. Based on those, you can always ask several follow-up questions. We can ask as many questions as we like in SE, and we get the best results when we "fine tune" them to bring out some excellent answers.

Comment: What is a "DUT"?

Comment: Device Under Test

Comment: Max Q is determined by preflight numerical simulation. All you need is the speed of the vehicle and its altitude (to get the ambient pressure). see https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49477/6944

Comment: @Organic Marble: Thanks for the link. SpaceX is likely to use a jig in the test nose cone perhaps for test on the ground, so I am interested in this alternative also.